# Collection items in Python

Tags: python

I have a collection of an item like below in my mongoDB database:

```
{u'Keywords': [[u'european', 7], [u'bill', 5], [u'uk', 5], [u'years', 4], [u'brexit', 4]], u'Link': u'http://www.bbc.com/
news/uk-politics-39042876', u'date': datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 21, 22, 47, 7, 463000), u'_id': ObjectId('58acc36b3040a218bc62c6d3')}
.....
```

These come from a mongo DB query

```
   mydb = client['BBCArticles']
    ##mydb.adminCommand({'setParameter': True, 'textSearchEnabled': True})
    my_collection = mydb['Articles']
    print 'Articles containing  higher occurences of the keyword is sorted as follow:'
    for doc in my_collection.find({"Keywords":{"$elemMatch" : {"$elemMatch": {"$in": [keyword.lower()]}}}}):
        print doc
```

However, I want to print documents as follow:

```
doc1
Kewords: european,bill, uk
Link:"http://www.bbc.com/"

doc2
....
```

Comment: Seems like quite arbitrary requirements to me. Why not the full url and why not all the keywords? Also where do `doc1` and `doc2` come from? Are they just in the format `docN` where `N` is just increases with each item? To improve your question you should describe the expected transformation and also show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your collection looks like a `list` of dictionaries, it should be iterable and parseable using a `for`-loop. If indeed you want only a portion of the url and keywords, this should work:

```
# c = your_collection, a list of dictionaries

from urlparse import urlparse

for n in range(len(c)):
    print 'doc{n}'.format(n=n+1)
    for k, v in c[n].iteritems():
        if k == 'Keywords':
            print k+':', ', '.join([str(kw[0]) for kw in v[0:3]])
        if k == 'Link':
            parsed_uri = urlparse( v )
            domain = '{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=parsed_uri)
            print k+':', '"{0}"\n'.format(domain)
```

prints:

```
doc1
Keywords: european, bill, uk
Link: "http://www.bbc.com/"
```